# OK to have XP and Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

With XP support ending in April 2014 it is worth creating a Ubuntu dual partition or am I better off just replacing XP with Ubuntu?

Comment: Is your decision to do so. You are free to do.

Comment: Your question seems to be about your worries of Windows XP end of support and not Ubuntu. You may wish to reword your question in order to tell us what are your worries about Ubuntu? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use XP from a computer with internet access after Microsoft finishes with patching the security holes in it. And this is unrelated to the thing whether you switch to Ubuntu or to anything else.

If you still have to use XP for compatibility with some programs I advise you to disable the network interface in XP and do your networking stuff from another, still supported OS, be it either another version of Windows, Linux, or anything else.

Comment: I wanted to keep XP because I've got some old software but sounds like it might be more risky than worth it. Where would I go to get the relevant (chipset, network, video, etc.) drivers for Ubuntu?

Comment: @AndyDavis Most of the drivers are integrated to the kernel/ubuntu, so there is a good chance that you wouldn't need to go anywhere.  Try out a live CD and check out that what of your hardwares work out of the box. If all is OK, then you can install. If some are not functional, then you should google for some solutions.

Answer (score 1):

**Try Ubuntu** without installing it on your hard-disk using *Ubuntu live disk*.From that you can understand which one is better whether to dualboot Windows and Ubuntu or replacing Windows with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using wine in Ubuntu and just ditch XP all together. If you end up hating Ubuntu there are many other options as well (Mint Kubuntu Debian Fedora Xubuntu and so on).